# Omit NA rows with rpy2

Tags: python, r, na, rpy2

This would be easy in plain R. For a data frame named counts and a column named hgnc it would be this:

```
counts <- na.omit(hgnc)
```

**How do I achieve the same thing in rpy2?** There doesn't seem to be an na_omit function as far as I can tell.

I tried selecting based on whether the field was `"<NA>"`, but I got maddeningly inconsistent results:

```
print r.dim(counts)
[   63677,       12]
print r.dim(counts.rx(counts.rx2('hgnc').ro == "<NA>", True))
[1] 6672   12
print r.dim(counts.rx(counts.rx2('hgnc').ro != "<NA>", True))
[1] 63677    12
```

Notice that it finds the rows that contain `<NA>` with ==, but then when I search for the rows that don't contain `<NA>` it just finds every row. The same does not happen for when I search for "" instead of `"<NA>"`:

```
print r.dim(counts.rx(counts.rx2('hgnc').ro == "", True))
[1] 27979    12
print r.dim(counts.rx(counts.rx2('hgnc').ro != "", True))
[1] 42370    12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any R code using `rpy2.robjects`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

# R SCRIPT
ro.r.source('yourRscript.R')

# R DATA FRAME
ro.globalenv['counts']

# OMIT NA ROWS
ro.r('na.omit(counts$hgnc)')
```

Comment: Wow I wish that this style of syntax were more prominent in the rpy2 documentation. This is so much cleaner and easier than what I've been trying to do. Thank you for including the extra lines, ridiculously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can call R functions that have a period "." in the name by using `ro.r("na.omit")(...)`, where the `...` is a list of python variables. For example:

```
In [1]: from rpy2 import robjects as ro

In [2]: x = ro.r("c(1,2,NA)")

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 
<FloatVector - Python:0x1073ab758 / R:0x7fbafba8b520>
[1.000000, 2.000000, NA_real_]

In [4]: ro.r("na.omit")(x)
Out[4]: 
<FloatVector - Python:0x1073b3f80 / R:0x7fbafaa415f8>
[1.000000, 2.000000]
```